# Phone wont unlock bootloader in adb

Tags: applications

So Ive tried to unlock my bootloader but its not working, ive followed the steps from this site to unlock it but its stuck on the unlock bootloader screen. I have two options to choose from yes or no I click yes but it doesnt work, yet I click no and it takes me back to choose from fastboot, recovery and normal. My phone is a Alcatel Pixi 4.

I have enabled developer mode enabled usb debugging. I also have confirmed the RSA fingerprint for the computer. Also I have enabled OEM unlock in dev settings. This is what my cmd prompt window loooks like. I will also take a photo of my alcatel frozen on bootloader screen.

```
C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
5HQGTCEQCAVS7TTS device

C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb reboot-bootloader
C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>fastboot oem unlock
...
```

This is what my phone looks like that im stuck on:

[image: photo]

does anyone know why this is happening or know how to fix?

Comment: Is your Volume up button working? I don't know why this wouldn't work. you have completed every step.

Comment: yeh the volume up key works perfectly fine tested it out no issues just when I go to unlock the bootloader that it doesnt allow me to unlock it for some reason weird...

Comment: When you press volume up on this screen what happens?

Comment: nothing happens when I press the volume up key, its like somewhere in the system theres a setting thats not allowing me to unlock the bootloader.

Answer (score -1):

issue has been resolved the bootloader is unlocked by default.